# RegEx to find Nested For Loop in VB

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a RegEx to find nested For loops in VBA / VB6 modules, for example:

```
For Loop1
   'enter code here

   For Loop2
       `enter code here
   Next
   'enter code here
Next
```

So far I have:

```
(?=For )(?s)(.*)(?=For )(?s)(.*)(?=Next )
```

Sadly the expression seems equally good at finding single For Next loops as nested For Next loops, not to mention methods with multiple (non-nested) For Next loops.

This is melting my brain - please help.  I don't understand how a single For Next loop is found given that (?=For) appears twice in the expression...

TIA

Comment: Someting like [this](https://regex101.com/r/fN4rI9/1)?

Comment: You will not be able to build a regex that will find these absolutely reliably. That's simply beyond what regex can do.

Comment: Hi @marsze yes I've read that a few times... I don't need this to be 100% reliable, this is to assist with a manual code review.  There are a LOT of nested For loops many of which should be refactored out to their own function, hence the question.  RegEx is the only tool that I can implement quickly and easily, imperfect as it is.

Comment: Hi @ThomasAyoub - first time the web page didn't load properly (text only)...  stared at it for ages then gave up.  Looked again and sure... it seems to work.  I am attempting to put the RegEx into MZ Tools 8 - Code Review function, should (as far as I understand it) be using the .Net RegEx... although your Expression seems to meet my need I can't get it working in MZ-Tools :-(   (yet)

Comment: Hi @ThomasAyoub using the website you linked to I got as far as this: https://regex101.com/r/fN4rI9/3  : (?s)For .*((?=For ).*)(?=Next) : it's an improvement over my original attempt - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is only supposed to assist with manual code review, assuming 4 spaces are used for indention, you might want to try the following approach:

```
(\s*)For[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+(\s+([\r\n]+)|(\1    (?!For)[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+))+(\1    For)
```

This will find a `For` inside another `For`, demo:

https://regex101.com/r/lV8oZ0/1

Comment: Ahh that's a good idea, yes the code is properly indented. That was one of the first things MZ-Tools did for me. Will test it out, thanks.

Comment: Yikes.... this RegEx crashed my PC but on RegEx101.com it seems to do the trick.  I think I can make it a little less resource intensive as my requirement is only to identify methods that contain at least 1 nested For Loop, so I only need to find the 1st match... unless I'm mistaken that should reduce the overhead :-/  Getting close, thanks :-D

Comment: I tried to simplify your expression but failed, the expression works however it takes a while to run - since I don't plan to use this routinely it suits my needs and  provides the most accurate result for the tools available.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions **by themselves** cannot match a complete for/content/next when said content can have an instance of a whole loop within it. However, **if the maximum depth of the loops is known beforehand,** this can be done. For instance, take this JavaScript code, where the contents of the file is in a variable called `file`:

```
// remove the literals here so that the script doesn't get confused by them
// see some of my other answers for how to do this
var depth = file.match(/\bFor\b/g).length;
return new RegExp('(?:\\bFor\\b.*?){' + depth + '}(?:.*?\\bNext\\b){' + depth + '}');
```

That should return a regular expression to match all the For/Next loops in `file`. Lookaheads are not necessary here.

Comment: Hi @RamenChef - Thanks. Yes the depth of nesting is known, (well so far as to say it wont be more than 2, will typically be 2). I'll take a look at your suggestion in the AM. Cheers,

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I don't think I will be able to use (or test) this approach as the expression needs to be a single shot, as in I don't think I have a way to calculate depth then reuse depth in the RegEx (the regex is entered into a form field)